# Sinatra and Activerecord "cannot load such file -- sinatra/activerecord"

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm following Micheal Herman's post on Sinatra + PostgreSQL + Heroku, put keep running into an error

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
```

when I try to launch the app ($ ruby app.rb) or create my database ( $ rake db:create_migration NAME=...) I keep receiving the following error:

```
cannot load such file -- sinatra/activerecord
```

sinatra-activerecord-1.2.3 is in my gemlist. What am i missing?

Comment: Are you requiring bundler? Did you run bundle install? Does bundle list show this gem as present?

Comment: @Casper, I have the same issue now and my answers are: yes, yes, yes.

Comment: Can you post the full app.rb & rakefile you're using?

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me after changing this line in environments.rb

```
sqlite:///dev.db
```

to

```
sqlite3:///dev.db
```